# Is it okay not to catchError in ngrx effect

Tags: angular, error-handling, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Let's assume that I have a following code:

```js
  fetchData$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fetchData),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.repository.fetchData().pipe(
          map(data => fetchDataSuccess({ data })),
          catchError(error => of(fetchDataFail({ error })))
        )
      )
    );
  });
```

In the system I've built, there is a custom handler bind to every http call, witch handles error. In a nutshell, it looks like this:

```js
  fetchData() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`https://api.com/getData`).pipe(this.handleError());
  }

  handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        this.notification.create('Oops something went wrong');
        throw err;
      })
    );
  }
```

Every time when http error occurs, there is a notification created and error is printed to the console (then read by a tool for error reporting). My question is: can I safely omit `catchError` in effect, if I'm not doing anything with this action there, besides actually dispatching it? Error is handled somewhere else, notification is displayed to the user, this action is not handled in reducer. If I remove this, won't this cause any performance / memory issues? I understand that this will cause error to be basically thrown and not be caught anywhere 
In the result effect will look like this:

```js
  fetchData$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fetchData),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.repository.fetchData().pipe(
          map(data => fetchDataSuccess({ data }))
        )
      )
    );
  });
```

I've tried looking for some articles about it, but none of them mentioned this kind of situation. When I changed the effect it works perfectly well.

Comment: How does `handleError` detect an error? In your example code it would always report one.

Comment: You are right, I oversimplified it. There is a `return pipe(catchError(...))` in `handleError` method – I've edited the post. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous versions of NgRx this WAS a problem.
If an error was thrown in the effect, than the effect would unsubscribe.

Currently the answer is yes and no.
The effect has a built-in error handler, but only for the first 10 errors.
You can extend this if you want by creating your own error handler.

```
   {
          provide: EFFECTS_ERROR_HANDLER,
          useValue: defaultEffectsErrorHandler,
        },
```

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/effects_error_handler.ts

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed. Is there anywhere information about it in documentation, or have I missed it? If not it would be helpful to include it